# GPX parser android - No content provider

Tags: java, android, gpx

In my application I would like to use a gpx file downloaded from the server.

I use  GPXParser from https://github.com/ticofab/android-gpx-parser .

When I was trying to parse gpx file, I got warring "java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider"

```
Gpx parsedGpx = null;
GPXParser parser = new GPXParser();
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(stringUrl));
parsedGpx = parser.parse(inputStream);
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: What is the value of `stringUrl` ? Give and example.  Given that your are trying to parse a string for the Uri suggests that the Uri is not of the of the right type for `getContentResolver`, so where did you get `stringUrl` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getContentResolver is to get data from a [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) not from any random Url, it is for getting data from other processes and usually takes the string form of `content://....`

You need to download the gpx first with something like [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) and it's `getInputStream()` method to get an `inputStream` to use with the parser.

Comment: `getContentResolver is to get data from a ContentResolver ` No. From a content provider.

Comment: @blackapps you are jumping a step / have a different take on the semantics. `getContentResolver`  returns a `ContentResolver` not a content provider as it might not need a content provider to get the data. You get data from the ContentResolver`, it gets the data from the content provider. It's multi step process, you are jumping over a step in a multiple step chain which continues with further steps with the content provider getting the data from elsewhere (memory, storage, network, etc).

Comment: The content resolver does not see any data. It opens an inputstream for you and then the data flows from content provider to you. The content resolver knows nothing of this. It does not even spy.

Comment: @blackapps the "data" can be an inputstream object or `outputstream` object or even `loadThumbnail` which returns a `Bitmap`, And for `file://` and `android.resource://` Uri types it does not even involve a content provider, you are mistaking `getContentResolver` with what data you get from for some Uri's you can get from it's `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` method via an `InputStream` object.